# Checkpoint/restore feature not working in Docker

Tags: git, docker, restore, checkpoint

I am totally new to docker and also not used to building software from github. I want to enable the checkpoint restore feature in docker.

I installed CRIU from here:

https://github.com/xemul/criu

This is how I built docker from the below repository:
https://github.com/boucher/docker/tree/boucher-cr

Docker Server Version: 1.10.3

Docker client version : 1.10.3

After running the make command in the newly cloned 'Docker' folder I got the below output.

> ---> Making bundle: binary (in bundles/1.7.0-dev/binary) Building: /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/bundles/1.7.0-dev/binary/docker-1.7.0-dev
>
> Created binary:
>   /go/src/github.com/docker/docker/bundles/1.7.0-dev/binary/docker-1.7.0-dev

I have not done anything else after running make command. Checkpoint restore feature is not yet enabled in docker. Did I miss any commands?

Answer (score 0):

They have release version if you donot want to compile by yourself. 
thanks for Mr.boucher.
https://github.com/boucher/docker/releases
docker-1.10.0-dev

you may refer to my blog.
http://xichenpro.com/2016/06/10/use-native-docker-checkpoint-restore-on-Ubuntu-14-04/

note: use ubuntu15.04 would be better if you donot want to patch the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but since I am in the same situation at the moment:

You may want to run `DOCKER_EXPERIMENTAL=1 make binary` to have the experimental features enabled.
After that a call to `./bundles/1.7.0-dev/binary/docker-1.7.0-dev --version` should show that you have an experimental build.
Also the `checkpoint` command should be available when printing `--help`.

I added a documentation entry for that topic. It will be available after review.